# Multiplication of matrix in to a vector in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix `m` and a vector `v`. I would like to multiply the matrix `m` into vetcor `v`and get a matrix whith same dimension as `m` means that multiply first element of `m` to `v` and .... How can I do this in R?

```
    m = matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), ncol=1)
    v = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    > z
      [,1]
 [1,]    1
 [2,]    4
 [3,]    9
 [4,]   16
 [5,]   25
```

Comment: This is what ordinary scalar multiplication would do. `?"*"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cross products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) can be obtained using the `%*%` operator:

```
> m = matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), ncol=1)
>     v = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

> m %*% v
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10
[3,]    3    6    9   12   15
[4,]    4    8   12   16   20
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25
> m * v
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    4
[3,]    9
[4,]   16
[5,]   25
```

Comment: `*` does not act only on the first column. In the example there is only 1 column, but compare with `matrix(1,ncol=2,nrow=3) * 2:4`.

Comment: Downvoting until the error in description of R's behavior is corrected. Please review the concept of recycling in any introductory R tutorial.

Comment: DWin, you could edit the answer, if it makes sense, I'll approve it. Ditto to Roland